# sinus generation and it's fft in radians

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

I'm trying to generate sine signal and display it's fft in radians, byt I meet several issues that I can't understand. Please find my script below:

```
clear all; close all; clc; 
fs = 10*pi; 
ts = 1/fs; 
t = 0:ts:2*pi; 
sine = cos(10*t); 
plot(t/pi,sine) 
sinefft = fft(sine); 
subplot(2,1,1) 
plot(abs(sinefft)) 
subplot(2,1,2) 
plot(abs(fftshift(sinefft)))
```

**Results**
[image]
[image]

**1. Why on first plot fft shows that cosine has a frequency 11 radians?**

**2. How to shift fft to achieve frequency domain around 0?**

I will be thankful for your explanations.

Maks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why on first plot fft shows that cosine has a frequency 11 radians?

The **array index number** of the cosine peak is 11.  The *frequency* is different.

Matlab indexes from 1, so the **FFT bin number** will be 10 (as we have a 0 bin in FFTs).

The *frequency* of that bin will be 
$$
\frac{2 \pi (11 - 1) }{N } = \frac{2 \pi 10}{ 198} = \frac{10\pi}{99}
$$
assuming your FFT length was 198.

Note that this will be a normalized frequency between 0 and $2\pi$ (or, if you prefer, $-\pi$ and +$\pi$).

> 2. How to shift fft to achieve frequency domain around 0?

Your use of `fftshift` does this in the second plot.  However, you need to set the $x$ axis by doing something like:

```
N = length(sinefft);
delta_omega = 2*pi/N; % rad/sec between FFT bins
omega = -pi:delta_omega:(pi - delta_omega)
plot(omega, abs(fftshift(sinefft)));
```

**Minor Correction** I previously had this frequency variable as `f`, it's actually `omega`.

> How to calculate now what frequency in Hz has this signal?

So the normalized frequency in radian per second is `omega`.  That ranges from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$ (modulo some end effects).

The normalized frequency in "Hz" is `f`. This will be `omega/2/pi`. This ranges from -0.5 to +0.5.

The frequency in terms of the sampling frequency will be `f_true = omega / pi / 2 * fs` (where `fs` is the sampling frequency).

Comment: Great! That's clearing a lot. But I have one question more, therefore I'm new in radians domain (it was always unclear for me, but I've made myself a goal to understand relation between w and f):
How to calculate now what frequency in Hz has this signal? Is it f = w/2*pi?

Comment: @MaksPiechota : Check out my update; I made a mistake earlier, and have tried to address the question in your comment.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your explanation.
But why delta_f = 2*pi/N? I see it works but I don't understand why it is independent from sampling frequency?

Comment: @MaksPiechota Once you've sampled, we don't really care about the sampling frequency as far as DFTs or filtering are concerned.  We just have data in an array, indexed by an integer.  We **do** care about the sampling frequency when we want to relate it to the "analog" world, just not once we're just working with numbers in an array. For the samples in the array, we only really care about normalized frequency (from 0 to 1 or -0.5 to +0.5 or in radian/second from -$\pi$ to |$\pi$).

Comment: Ok. So in nominator we have $2\pi$ because this is the range that we want to have in out fft x axis?

Comment: Right, the FFT (DFT) doesn't care about Hz. It just cares about bins or, at a push, normalized frequency which ranges from 0 to $2\pi$.